# iOS UITextField won't become first responder after view reload

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, ios7, uitextfielddelegate, becomefirstresponder

When my view (view A) loads, a UITextField becomes the first responder. I can then push a new view controller (view B), but when I pop that view controller back to view A, the UITextfield doesn't become the first responder anymore. I have to touch the textfield so that the keyboard will pop up. I'm using XIB's if that helps.

I tried setting the first responder in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method, or the viewWillLayoutSubviews but still nothing. I even used an NSNotification to detect if view B has been dismissed and then pop up the keyboard but nothing. I have no idea what else to do.
It's like view A is completely dead.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to put it in viewWillAppear. Also for sanity check, is the textfield nil?

Comment: Tried already. All the methods. And no, it's not nil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated was the solution

Comment: I ran into the same problem. I had attached a inputAccessoryView to the textfield so I could see it appearing but the keyboard did not appear. Moving becomeFirstResponder into the viewDidAppear resolved my issue.